# Close infoWindow when new opens?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
new google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close(map, marker);  //the code is not working..
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Store all the info windows in an array. And use the following function to close the currently open window.

I.E:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

infoWindowArray.push(infoWindow);


function resetInfoWindow(){
    if(infoWindowArray){
        for(i in infoWindowArray){
            infoWindowArray[i].close();
        }
    }
}
```

Call the function `resetInfoWindow()` like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        resetInfoWindow();
        infoWindow.setContent(str1);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
```